# How to send mail from iphone Application?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I want to send email from my application. How can i send it?

Comment: Try [this](http://icodeblog.com/2009/02/20/iphone-programming-tutorial-using-openurl-to-send-email-from-your-app/) tutorial.

Answer (score 3):

Documentation of [MFMailComposeViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html) is the first place you should start with.

Generally, I don't recommend tutorial links but [this link might be useful.](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-101-send-email-iphone-app/)